# Variable Value Is Printing '[ object Object]'

Tags: javascript

I am using this script below to take the value from my URL and display the value within a input field.

```
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
}();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("field34").value = QueryString;
}, false);
```

For some reason when my variable `QueryString` prints to the screen it displays this within my input field:

```
[object Object]
```

However when I console.log that variable I get this:

```
console.log(QueryString)
undefined
Object { value: "YX57WDL" }
```

Which has the value in it I would like to print to the screen.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `QueryString` is assigned an object. When you assign an object to an attribute of DOM element, the object is cast to string.

In JavaScript, whenever an object is cast to string, its [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method is called. By default it returns `[object Object]`.

If you want another string representation for your object you can either override its `.toString()` method or avoid implicit casting by constructing a string by hand, e.g., with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Answer (score 1):

you can print it as follows:

```
QueryString.value
```